# Cannot change color of TextView using appcompat on Android

Tags: android, colors, themes, compatibility, android-appcompat

I am facing this weird behavior on Android using AppCompat.

My theme is the following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/gray_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.GreenButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

In my layout I have this button:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/login_button_login"
 style="@style/MyTheme.GreenButton"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:text="Log in"/>
```

Compiling on Android 6 works perfectly. However, on Android 5, the text color of the button is black and cannot be changed using xml textColor. It works by using setTextColor directly in the code though.

What am I missing? Why would the appcompat theme be different according to the sdk version? This problem also affects my textviews that are all gray.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with different `TextView`s, which turned black out of a sudden.

I solved this by downgrading all support-v7 libraries to the **latest stable version**, at this moment 23.3.0, http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat